# SQL Server - Complex Scenario - comparing statuses and populating values to proceeding row

Tags: sql, sql-server, gaps-and-islands

In SQL Server, I am having source data like this. The as_of_date|issue_id|issue_status_name|prev_issue_status_name are in my source table and desired output is what I am looking for.

Basically need to compare issue_status_name with prev_issue_status_name and when prev_issue_status_name in (null,open,draft) and issue_status_name in (pending sustainability, pending validation, closed) then we should set the as_of_date and populate in preceding rows until reverse happens.

I tried to do this with first writing case statement to populate 1 else 0 then increment the number but I am not sure how to do for each occurance. Can someone guide me in the right direction please?

| as_of_date | issue_id | issue_status_name | prev_issue_status_name | desired_output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12/31/2019 | 123456 | Draft | NULL | NULL |
| 1/1/2020 | 123456 | Draft | Draft | NULL |
| 1/2/2020 | 123456 | Draft | Draft | NULL |
| 1/3/2020 | 123456 | Pending Validation | Draft | 1/3/2020 |
| 1/4/2020 | 123456 | Pending Validation | Pending Validation | 1/3/2020 |
| 1/5/2020 | 123456 | Pending Validation | Pending Validation | 1/3/2020 |
| 1/6/2020 | 123456 | Pending Validation | Pending Validation | 1/3/2020 |
| 1/7/2020 | 123456 | Open | Pending Validation | NULL |
| 1/8/2020 | 123456 | Open | Open | NULL |
| 1/9/2020 | 123456 | Open | Open | NULL |
| 1/10/2020 | 123456 | Open | Open | NULL |
| 1/11/2020 | 123456 | Pending Sustainability | Open | 1/11/2020 |
| 1/12/2020 | 123456 | Pending Sustainability | Pending Sustainability | 1/11/2020 |
| 1/13/2020 | 123456 | Pending Sustainability | Pending Sustainability | 1/11/2020 |
| 1/14/2020 | 123456 | Pending Sustainability | Pending Sustainability | 1/11/2020 |
| 1/15/2020 | 123456 | Pending Validation | Pending Sustainability | 1/11/2020 |
| 1/16/2020 | 123456 | Pending Validation | Pending Validation | 1/11/2020 |
| 1/17/2020 | 123456 | Pending Validation | Pending Validation | 1/11/2020 |
| 1/18/2020 | 123456 | Pending Validation | Pending Validation | 1/11/2020 |
| 1/19/2020 | 123456 | Pending Validation | Pending Validation | 1/11/2020 |
| 1/20/2020 | 123456 | Pending Validation | Pending Validation | 1/11/2020 |
| 1/21/2020 | 123456 | Open | Pending Validation | NULL |
| 1/22/2020 | 123456 | Open | Open | NULL |
| 1/23/2020 | 123456 | Open | Open | NULL |
| 1/24/2020 | 123456 | Open | Open | NULL |
| 1/25/2020 | 123456 | Open | Open | NULL |
| 1/26/2020 | 123456 | Open | Open | NULL |
| 1/27/2020 | 123456 | Closed | Open | 1/27/2020 |
| 1/28/2020 | 123456 | Closed | Closed | 1/27/2020 |
| 1/29/2020 | 123456 | Closed | Closed | 1/27/2020 |
| 1/30/2020 | 123456 | Closed | Closed | 1/27/2020 |
| 1/31/2020 | 123456 | Closed | Closed | 1/27/2020 |

I tried the following:

CASE WHEN issue_status_name in (pending validation, closed, pending sustainability) and prev_issue_status_name in (null, open, draft) then sum(case when prev_issue_status_name not in (pending validation, closed, pending sustainability) then as_of_date else null

But it's not giving correct output.

Comment: This sounds like a gaps and islands problem. You to appear to want to look for a transition in status to drive it.

Comment: @shawnt00 can you please elaborate?

Comment: If you post more readable sample data and desired output then I might be able to elaborate.

Comment: done, sorry I am new to this and took me a while to figure out how to convert into table. THe desired output column contains how I am expecting data to look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't seem to actually care about previous status per se but rather that a run of consecutive statuses of the three interesting ones (pending/closed) should be treated as a unit and then return the first `as_of_date` from among them. This uses a standard row-numbering gaps and islands technique:

```
with data as (
    select *,
        row_number() over (
            partition by issue_id order by as_of_date) -
        row_number() over (
            partition by issue_id, output_flag order by as_of_date) as grp
    from T cross apply (values (
        case when issue_status_name
                  in ('Pending Validation', 'Pending Sustainability', 'Closed')
             then 1 else 0 end)) v(output_flag) /* not sure what's a good name */
)
select as_of_date, issue_id, issue_status_name, prev_issue_status_name,
    case when output_flag = 1
         then min(as_of_date) over (partition by issue_id, grp) end as desired_output
from data;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/6i92BbzL?hide=2

Comment: Thanks @shawnt00 this worked like a charm. I was kind of on the right track but I was not aware of this cross apply values functionality.

Comment: @Poojan `cross apply ... values` is just an easy way to name the expression so you don't have to repeat it. The heart of the query is where it computes the `grp` number.

Comment: Thanks @shawnt00 that makes sense. The only place I need to figure out now is the 1st row, in scenarios where issue_status_name is pendin validation but prev_issue_status_name is null, it is unnecessary going create output flag = 1 because now we are not looking at prev_issue_status.